# Line numbers in Silverlight stack trace

Tags: silverlight, stack-trace, pdb-files

I'm trying to get line numbers to display in my silverlight stack trace - for this I need the pdb files deployed with the xap. I've tried including them in the Xap file (xap file stops working), and deploying them on the web server (with appropriate mime type set for pdbs), but nothing seems to work. I can get IL offset of the failure, but would prefer to get the full line number when debugging issues outside of production.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Is this possible?